# Typesetting multiletter variables with subscripts and mixed formatting

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, typography, bm

Through my research on this website I've found the best way to typeset multiletter variables is using `\mathit`. However, if the variable has mixed formatting (i.e. bold, italic and roman) or super/subscript the results are not satisfactory with regards to spacing.

For my case, I'm trying to denote perturbations (denoted `$\delta$`) to variables `$f_0$` and `$\bm{f}_1$`. Simply prepending the delta creates too much space, while putting the entire group in `\mathit` affects the subscript spacing and the bold font. I have attached my best attempts as a MWE below.

It would be helpful if there was a command called `\mathgroup` or something that would denote a multiletter variable without affecting formatting.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
% Case 1
$ \mathit{\delta f_\mathrm{0}}$ has less subscript spacing between $f$ and 0 than \\
$\delta f_0$ and even less than than \\
$ \mathit{\delta f}_0$

% Case 2: The only way I've found to achieve something close to what I want except for spacing
$\mathit{\delta \bm{{f_{\mbox{\unboldmath$\scriptstyle 1$}}}}} $ appears identical to \\
$ \delta \bm{f}_1$ the following are not solutions either\\
$ \mathit{\delta \bm{{f}}_\mathrm{1}}$ \\
$ \mathit{\delta \bm{{f}}}_1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there are no multi-letter identifiers here, why use \mathit at all?

Comment: @davidcarlisle `\delta f_0` is a multi-letter identifier. I do not consider `\delta` to be an operator for my purposes. Therefore I require the spacing between the `\delta` and the `f_0` to be reduced somehow. Perhaps `\mathit` isn't the right solution, but I haven't come across any others.

Comment: mathematically perhaps, but not to tex, the reason to use mathit  is that adjacent letters _in the math italic font_ are designed to look separated so should not be used as a "word", but that does not apply to any of the examples here,

Comment: `\mathit` is good for multiletter identifiers; here you seem to want kerning between `\delta` and `f`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the tip. Kerning does work, but as I also have other places where I use the `\delta` notation I wanted to find a more consistent method than playing around with kerning for each different quantity that is perturbed. (For example, sometimes I have to use \mkern-1.5mu or \mkern-1mu to get satisfactory results, and was hoping this could be automated somehow.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to kern the `\delta` with the next letter, pushing back an ‘f’ more than other letters.

I wouldn't do it, actually, but here's a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\prt}{\mathop{}\!\delta\check@f}
\newcommand{\check@f}{%
  \@ifnextchar f{\mspace{-3mu}}{\check@bmf}%
}
\newcommand{\check@bmf}{%
  \@ifnextchar\bm{\check@bmf@i}{\mspace{-1.5mu}}%
}
\newcommand{\check@bmf@i}[2]{% #1 is \bm, #2 is the letter
  \if f\unexpanded{#2}%
    \mspace{-3mu}%
  \else
    \mspace{-1.5mu}%
  \fi
  \bm{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\prt g \prt f \prt\bm{f} \prt\bm{g}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what no L3! I'm shocked.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle “Proof of concept”. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Thanks for coming up with this. While I half-agree with the statement that one 'shouldn't' do this (would you just use `\delta` and call it a day?), it definitely meets my original specs. Although perhaps the 'kerning table' might end up needing to be too complicated. However, I think half of my question stemmed from a misunderstanding of what the `\mathit` command really did. I presumed that normal math mode inserts extra space around _every_ letter. Trying out your example and comparing with `\mathit` I found that the latter has no effect on `\delta g` which is not what I expected.

Comment: @JonathanBrodrick With `\mathit{\delta f}` you get a different ‘f’, that's why it appears to be nearer the delta.

Comment: @egreg Much clearer now thanks, should have done more reading around on `\mathit` I guess. Now I'll remember it changes _letters_ not spacing.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

$ \delta f_0$ $ \delta \bm{f}_1$


$ \delta\!f_0$ $ \delta\!\bm{f}_1$


$ \delta \mkern-2mu f_0$ $ \delta \mkern-2mu \bm{f}_1$

\end{document}
```

`\mathit` is not appropriate here as there are no adjacent (latin) letters that need to be typeset as a word. i would probably use the first line, but if you want tighter spacing you can add a negative kern, I find the standard `\!` (-3mu  by default) too much, but perhaps -2mu is an improvement.

Comment: Thanks David, I think this is probably the best solution, but was somehow hoping the kern amount could be automated. For another case even `\delta\mkern-1.5mu\bm{Q} ` is too much, and it seems pretty painful to play around with kern amount for each variable... I realise I'm probably just being overly worried about these things...

Comment: @JonathanBrodrick I would never put this in a document inline just use macros in each case `\df` `\dbmf` say defined as above then `\dQ` defined with a different value, then you only need to tune each letter once.